# R Parallel, is it better to create a new cluster everytime you use parallel apply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using `parLapply` function on 20 cores. I guess it is the same for the other function `parSapply` etc...

First, is it a bad practice to pass a cluster as an argument into a function so that the function can then dispatch the use of the cluster between different subfunctions?

Second, I pass this cluster argument into a function so i suppose it is the same cluster everytime i use `parLapply`, would it be better to use a new cluster for every `parLapply` call?

Thanks

Rgds

Comment: I would be interested in a modified vsn of Question One: is there any functional difference between passing the cluster and not passing the cluster as an argument to the main function?

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in parallel computing but will venture an answer anyway.

**1)** It is not bad practice to pass the cluster around as a function argument. It is just a collection of connections to worker processes, similar to connections to a file.

**2)** Restarting the cluster between calls is not needed. There will be problems if something has gone seriously wrong with a worker process, but in that case I would recommend cancelling the whole computation and restarting the master process too.

Comment: It seems that the calculation slows down the more i use the cluster for different parallel apply.

Comment: That's odd. I Have had similar problems with slow execution and sometimes even lost workers, if I abort and try to restart a parallel computation. But my only remedy to that has been to abort and restart the whole thing. It's hard to tell what is the cause because it is so system specific.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad practice to pass cluster objects as function arguments, so I don't see anything wrong with using them to dispatch between different sub-functions.

The problem with creating cluster objects for each operation is that it may take significant time, especially when starting many workers via ssh on a cluster, for example. However, it may be useful in some cases, and I think that that may be the purpose of Fork clusters, which are created by the makeForkCluster function in the parallel package. Fork cluster workers are very much like the workers forked by mclapply, which does create workers every time it's called. However, I think this is rarely done.